# Quiver list and labeling vectors of my inputs u,d, and r

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I label each vector of each input component, say u$_1$..., d$_1$..., on my graph at each vector's respective starting point. I want to see if there is a clustering of certain vectors like u$_30$-u$_50$ are all near each other, for example. Here is my code:

```
fx = [1.01, 1.0165376460248143, 1.016585505356985,...
    1.0166786731186357, 1.0166445649045002, 1.01684528204491,...
    1.0168363943981442, 1.0169505828006045, 1.0169903647693619,...
    1.0170588800755562, 1.0170214556321182, 1.0171007103163394,...
    1.0170611565299144, 1.0171737504115423, 1.0171325089936156,...
    1.0173884633568437, 1.0173821295549914, 1.017540453473392,...
    1.0176091468862674, 1.0177647297690604, 1.017711866139699,...
    1.0177536635811828, 1.0178254876275734, 1.0173994306983212,...
    1.0200331803664529, 1.0232411092365432, 1.0232773133875106,...
    1.023383936276914, 1.0233275057530007, 1.023510835824228,...
    1.0234461433923472, 1.023507118352957, 1.0237210297124908,...
    1.0236390252916325, 1.0237007559499636, 1.0239084387662698,...
    1.0238131746118633, 1.024266374303865, 1.024212732428539,...
    1.02440393427416, 1.0245390401237269, 1.0252178000353167,...
    1.0252021019242434, 1.0275875709904758, 1.0275871039342042];

fy = [0.99, 0.99, 0.9899194500620327, 0.9897134368447225,...
    0.9899339650105077, 0.9895259027418399, 0.9898115223446341,...
    0.9896762515189842, 0.9896129792784014, 0.9894766621994305,...
    0.9896189382715079, 0.9894614440540032, 0.9896292673356496,...
    0.9894095770062209, 0.989655005387203, 0.9892019096930893,...
    0.9894189058876284, 0.9892732425545386, 0.9891916768216495,...
    0.9889512723219249, 0.9892071461243063, 0.9891515372181835,...
    0.9890346980816267, 0.9901802532401042, 0.9892771992437573,...
    0.9881487558751526, 0.9880037699743045, 0.9875669935217211,...
    0.9878502051001951, 0.9872010568874899, 0.9875329139453003,...
    0.9873775054641964, 0.9868251990627905, 0.9871082986923524,...
    0.9869819983991632, 0.9865548473263468, 0.9867867860622922,...
    0.9859765136441385, 0.9861731333993694, 0.9859212446482857,...
    0.9857475603282838, 0.9848759880952044, 0.9850648602644492,...
    0.9821891156159342, 0.9822254068452594];

fz =[0.01, -0.0014683388934621459, -0.0028093690242636917,...
    -0.006255424514110392, -0.002405171080788649, -0.009167776104980133,...
    0.0003750210183572269, -0.001823375333180016, -0.002906415137850454,...
    -0.005227263048381278, -0.0028662319950483552, -0.0055329993182467365,...
    -0.0027458980004112996, -0.00644276568444028, -0.00226410433801184,...
    -0.009832266892691467, 0.0012478354917326469, -0.001163969711179093,...
    -0.0026270200357900887, -0.006946260715800828, -0.00188587841967576,...
    -0.002880843788516535, -0.0049636661241180685, 0.015586949435911355,...
    0.010368914010693711, -0.0010649331940053245, -0.002328942248654949,...
    -0.006634620630021168, -0.0020052485893380344, -0.008543368794125199,...
    -0.00044976575279103564, -0.0019790036016751333, -0.008330963679008077,...
    -0.0006481277669472506, -0.0020539789179887767, -0.0075781311330381336,...
    -0.001294365366809558, -0.011629381859506432, 0.003447063734076782,...
    0.0011256038145771368, -0.0008637305140054806, -0.012865086502170518,...
    0.005283762238371167, -0.016926299226379265, 0.011993515880473204];

x = [1.01, 1.0165376460248143, 1.016585505356985, 1.0166786731186357,...
    1.0166445649045002, 1.01684528204491, 1.0168363943981442,...
    1.0169505828006045, 1.0169903647693619, 1.0170588800755562,...
    1.0170214556321182, 1.0171007103163394, 1.0170611565299144,...
    1.0171737504115423, 1.0171325089936156, 1.0173884633568437,...
    1.0173821295549914, 1.017540453473392, 1.0176091468862674,...
    1.0177647297690604, 1.017711866139699, 1.0177536635811828,...
    1.0178254876275734, 1.0173994306983212, 1.0200331803664529,...
    1.0232411092365432, 1.0232773133875106, 1.023383936276914,...
    1.0233275057530007, 1.023510835824228, 1.0234461433923472,...
    1.023507118352957, 1.0237210297124908, 1.0236390252916325,...
    1.0237007559499636, 1.0239084387662698, 1.0238131746118633,...
    1.024266374303865, 1.024212732428539, 1.02440393427416,...
    1.0245390401237269, 1.0252178000353167, 1.0252021019242434,...
    1.0275875709904758, 1.0275871039342042];

y = [0.99, 0.99, 0.9899194500620327, 0.9897134368447225,...
    0.9899339650105077, 0.9895259027418399, 0.9898115223446341,...
    0.9896762515189842, 0.9896129792784014, 0.9894766621994305,...
    0.9896189382715079, 0.9894614440540032, 0.9896292673356496,...
    0.9894095770062209, 0.989655005387203, 0.9892019096930893,...
    0.9894189058876284, 0.9892732425545386, 0.9891916768216495,...
    0.9889512723219249, 0.9892071461243063, 0.9891515372181835,...
    0.9890346980816267, 0.9901802532401042, 0.9892771992437573,...
    0.9881487558751526, 0.9880037699743045, 0.9875669935217211,...
    0.9878502051001951, 0.9872010568874899, 0.9875329139453003,...
    0.9873775054641964, 0.9868251990627905, 0.9871082986923524,...
    0.9869819983991632, 0.9865548473263468, 0.9867867860622922,...
    0.9859765136441385, 0.9861731333993694, 0.9859212446482857,...
    0.9857475603282838, 0.9848759880952044, 0.9850648602644492,...
    0.9821891156159342, 0.9822254068452594];

z =[0.01, -0.0014683388934621459, -0.0028093690242636917,...
    -0.006255424514110392, -0.002405171080788649, -0.009167776104980133,...
    0.0003750210183572269, -0.001823375333180016, -0.002906415137850454,...
    -0.005227263048381278, -0.0028662319950483552, -0.0055329993182467365,...
    -0.0027458980004112996, -0.00644276568444028, -0.00226410433801184,...
    -0.009832266892691467, 0.0012478354917326469, -0.001163969711179093,...
    -0.0026270200357900887, -0.006946260715800828, -0.00188587841967576,...
    -0.002880843788516535, -0.0049636661241180685, 0.015586949435911355,...
    0.010368914010693711, -0.0010649331940053245, -0.002328942248654949,...
    -0.006634620630021168, -0.0020052485893380344, -0.008543368794125199,...
    -0.00044976575279103564, -0.0019790036016751333, -0.008330963679008077,...
    -0.0006481277669472506, -0.0020539789179887767, -0.0075781311330381336,...
    -0.001294365366809558, -0.011629381859506432, 0.003447063734076782,...
    0.0011256038145771368, -0.0008637305140054806, -0.012865086502170518,...
    0.005283762238371167, -0.016926299226379265, 0.011993515880473204];

figure
q = quiver3(fx,fy,fz,x,y,z)
```

The problem is that I want to label the starting point of each vector:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
q = quiver3(fx,fy,fz,x,y,z)
text(fx,fy,fz,num2str((1:numel(fx)).'))
```

The first 3 inputs are the coordinates of the label and the next input is a list (column character array or a cell-array) of the labels. I don't understand how your labeling is working (i.e. what is u$_1$ or d$_1$), so I just numbered the vectors from 1 to 45.

[image]

Comment: Thanks EBH! You helped me finish a research project at a summer REU!